# Как отсортировать коллекцию

Tags: c#, сортировка, linq

Есть такой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
}
class demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<test> i = new List<test> { new test() { Name = "kdsj", dt = new DateTime(1988, 12, 22) } };
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "1", dt = new DateTime(1988, 1, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "2", dt = new DateTime(1999, 2, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "3", dt = new DateTime(2015, 6, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "4", dt = new DateTime(1888, 5, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "5", dt = new DateTime(1978, 4, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "6", dt = new DateTime(1900, 12, 22) } );
        i.Add( new test() { Name = "7", dt = new DateTime(2002, 7, 22) } );

        Console.WriteLine(i[0].dt);
    }
}
```

Нужно отсортировать данную коллекцию по дате. Но нужно это сделать без реализации интерфейса `IComparable<>, IComparer` в объекте `Test` и без каких либо переопределений методов в `Test`, а чисто только использую методы расширений `Linq` и / или методы самой коллекции типа `List`. Возможно ли это сделать ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
i = i.OrderBy(x => x.dt).ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я пытался через Sort с извращениями. Но все проще оказалось.